# Need Transfer Value PHP

Tags: php, html

I am creating a new website. For that website I will need to transfer a quantity and amount value from one if condition statement into another if condition statement. Both if statements are accessed by separate submit buttons named "checkamt" & "buy".

I need to transfer the "quantity",  "value",  and "net" values to and from the *checkamt* `if` statement to the *buy* `if` statement.

Here's my code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="checkamt" value="Check Amount"/>
<input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy"/>
</form>

   <?php
      if(isset($_POST[checkamt]))
      {
          $qun=1;
          $val=5000;
          $total=$qun*$val;
      }

      if(isset($_POST[buy]))
      {
          echo $qun;
          echo $val;
          echo $total;
      }
   ?>
```

Comment: Would it make sense in your application to have the "checkamt" value processed as a different type of input, either a radio, checkbox or hidden element?

Comment: I'm afraid to answer this. It looks simple but I can't really make out what you're asking. Can you or someone clean that up a bit?

Comment: Whether it is possible to send value from one if statement to other if statement.?

Comment: No clue what you are asking. Need to use better English translatation of the problem and expected behaviour.

Comment: You need nested `if` statements? Or you need to define variables in a higher scope than your `if`?

Comment: OP wants to be able to use the values computed with the previous if statement?????

Comment: I think I'm getting a different interpretation than most, but if I am understanding your question correctly, just put those buttons in 2 different <form> tags instead of both buttons in one.

Comment: I rolled back the edit since it changed the question completely.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem you're having is that variables don't persist on page change. If you want that, you'll need to use a session. First, you must call `session_start` before anything, including HTML, is sent to the user. Then, you can use the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="checkamt" value="Check Amount"/>
<input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy"/>
</form>

   <?php
      if(isset($_POST[checkamt]))
      {
          $_SESSION['qun']=1;
          $_SESSION['val']=5000;
          $_SESSION['total']=$qun*$val;
      }

      if(isset($_POST[buy]))
      {
          echo $_SESSION['qun'];
          echo $_SESSION['val'];
          echo $_SESSION['total'];
      }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Improve your English! Not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to share the values of your variables between the two `if`s? You have to declare them at a higher scope than your `if`:

```
<?php
  $qun = 0;
  $val = 0;
  $total = 0;

  if(isset($_POST[checkamt]))
  {
      $qun=1;
      $val=5000;
      $total=$qun*$val;
  }

  if(isset($_POST[buy]))
  {
      echo $qun;
      echo $val;
      echo $total;
  }
?>
```

Comment: +1 for the person named Houssein asking him to improve his English

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer.  Please help me. how to improve my english.. i am studying 9 standard in AMIC Metric School, Mumbai.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting the question right, but why not do something like this :

```
  if(isset($_POST[checkamt]) || isset($_POST[buy]))
  {
      $qun=1;
      $val=5000;
      $total=$qun*$val;

      echo $qun;
      echo $val;
      echo $total;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. But the actual problem is the two different if statements can pass their values..

Answer (score 0):

You need to track your variables between the different forms. You can use SESSION like Xeon06 suggested, or do the following. I'm only showing for `$qun`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkamt'])) {
    $qun=1;
}

if(isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    echo $qun;
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="qun" value="<?php echo $qun; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="checkamt" value="Check Amount"/>
<input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy"/>
</form>
```